# In SVN Post-Commit hook script, why we need to use mailer.py instead of commit-email.pl?

Tags: python, svn, svn-hooks, post-commit-hook

I read in some [answer threads](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11329146/4374739) that commit-email.pl is deprecated and we need to use mailer.py.

Could you please explain why? What kinda issue will arise if I use commit-email.pl? Is there any advantage of using mailer.py?

Comment: Could you link to or reference somewhere you might have read this?

Comment: Yeah, Please refer this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11315754/svn-hook-mailer-py-configuration/11329146#11329146